# Query Taking time to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that fetches data from two tables but it takes too much time to fetch data. The browser loads and shows nothing as a result. When I run this query in the MySQL database, it takes a long time to execute.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    library_new_item AS library 
    LEFT JOIN library_items_barcode AS boorcode ON library.lib_item_id=boorcode.lib_items_id 
ORDER BY 
    library.lib_item_id ASC 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of your database

Comment: Define **long**. Better share the `Explain` output

Comment: MySQL offers the `Explain` feature to help you find the culprits of slow executing queries. You want to check if you forgot to define an index for the selection columns `library.lib_item_id` and `boorcode.lib_items_id`.

Comment: are you using windows 10?

Comment: Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AbdullahMallik window 7

Answer (score 0):

Unless you post your DB structure, or share the `Explain` output or the error message, it'd be impossible for us to answer. But if you want us to take a shot in the dark, this could possibly be the issue:

on library.lib_**item_id** = boorcode.lib_**items_id**

Comment: all the column name are correct and i have around 10000 data and if i fetch limit 10 then it works

Comment: What happens when you do a "Full Join" with the limit set as 100?